# Python giving vague error when trying to parse JSON object

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the peopledata API at peopledatalabs.com to retrieve data. I am using the sample python code located at https://docs.peopledatalabs.com/docs/quickstart

which is:

```
import requests

API_KEY = # YOUR API KEY

###

pdl_url = "https://api.peopledatalabs.com/v4/person?api_key={}&".format(API_KEY)
param_string = "name=sean thorne&company=peopledatalabs.com"

json_response = requests.get(pdl_url + param_string).json()

# OR

pdl_url = "https://api.peopledatalabs.com/v4/person"

params = {
    "api_key": API_KEY,
    "name": ["sean thorne"],    
    "company": ["peopledatalabs.com"]
}

json_response = requests.get(pdl_url,  params=params).json()
```

json_response returns:

```
{'status': 200,
 'likelihood': 5,
 'data': {'id': 'yj5RUCSORrirXf2sf3gR',
  'skills': [{'name': 'social media'},
   {'name': 'strategic partnerships'},
   {'name': 'public speaking'},
   {'name': 'sales'},
   {'name': 'photoshop'},
   {'name': 'networking'},
   {'name': 'mobile marketing'},
   {'name': 'start ups'},
   {'name': 'business development'},
   {'name': 'fundraising'},
   {'name': 'seo'},
   {'name': 'strategy'},
   {'name': 'idea generation'},
   {'name': 'enterprise technology sales'},
   {'name': 'entrepreneurship'},
   {'name': 'social networking'},
   {'name': 'creative strategy'},
   {'name': 'time management'},
   {'name': 'product management'},
   {'name': 'social media marketing'},
   {'name': 'css'},
   {'name': 'https'},
   {'name': 'saas'},
   {'name': 'management'},
   {'name': 'project management'},
   {'name': 'public relations'},
   {'name': 'marketing communications'},
   {'name': 'sales/marketing and strategic partnerships'},
   {'name': 'marketing strategy'},
   {'name': 'mobile devices'},
   {'name': 'installation'},
   {'name': 'company culture'},
   {'name': 'strategic vision'},
   {'name': 'html5'},
   {'name': 'hiring'}],
  'industries': [{'name': 'computer software', 'is_primary': True}],
  'interests': [{'name': 'location based services'},
   {'name': 'mobile'},
   {'name': 'social media'},
   {'name': 'colleges'},
   {'name': 'university students'},
   {'name': 'consumer internet'},
   {'name': 'college campuses'}],
  'profiles': [{'network': 'linkedin',
    'ids': ['145991517'],
    'clean': 'linkedin.com/in/seanthorne',
    'aliases': [],
    'username': 'seanthorne',
    'is_primary': True,
    'url': 'http://www.linkedin.com/in/seanthorne'},
   {'network': 'linkedin',
    'ids': [],
    'clean': 'linkedin.com/in/sean-thorne-9b9a8540',
    'aliases': ['linkedin.com/pub/sean-thorne/40/a85/9b9'],
    'username': 'sean-thorne-9b9a8540',
    'is_primary': False,
    'url': 'http://www.linkedin.com/in/sean-thorne-9b9a8540'},
   {'network': 'twitter',
    'ids': [],
    'clean': 'twitter.com/seanthorne5',
    'aliases': [],
    'username': 'seanthorne5',
    'url': 'http://www.twitter.com/seanthorne5'},
   {'network': 'angellist',
    'ids': [],
    'clean': 'angel.co/475041',
    'aliases': [],
    'username': '475041',
    'url': 'http://www.angel.co/475041'}],
  'emails': [{'address': 'sthorne@uoregon.edu',
    'type': None,
    'sha256': 'e206e6cd7fa5f9499fd6d2d943dcf7d9c1469bad351061483f5ce7181663b8d4',
    'domain': 'uoregon.edu',
    'local': 'sthorne'},
   {'address': 'sean@peopledatalabs.com',
    'type': 'current_professional',
    'sha256': '138ea1a7076bb01889af2309de02e8b826c27f022b21ea8cf11aca9285d5a04e',
    'domain': 'peopledatalabs.com',
    'local': 'sean'}],
  'phone_numbers': [{'E164': '+14155688415',
    'number': '+14155688415',
    'type': None,
    'country_code': '1',
    'national_number': '4155688415',
    'area_code': '415'}],
  'birth_date_fuzzy': '1990',
  'birth_date': None,
  'gender': 'male',
  'primary': {'job': {'company': {'name': 'people data labs',
     'founded': '2015',
     'industry': 'information technology and services',
     'location': {'locality': 'san francisco',
      'region': 'california',
      'country': 'united states'},
     'profiles': ['linkedin.com/company/peopledatalabs',
      'linkedin.com/company/1640694639'],
     'website': 'peopledatalabs.com',
     'size': '11-50'},
    'locations': [],
    'end_date': None,
    'start_date': '2015-03',
    'title': {'levels': ['owner'],
     'name': 'co-founder',
     'functions': ['co founder']},
    'last_updated': '2019-05-01'},
   'location': {'name': 'san francisco, california, united states',
    'locality': 'san francisco',
    'region': 'california',
    'country': 'united states',
    'last_updated': '2019-01-01',
    'continent': 'north america'},
   'name': {'first_name': 'sean',
    'middle_name': None,
    'last_name': 'thorne',
    'clean': 'sean thorne'},
   'industry': 'computer software',
   'personal_emails': [],
   'linkedin': 'linkedin.com/in/seanthorne',
   'work_emails': ['sean@peopledatalabs.com'],
   'other_emails': ['sthorne@uoregon.edu']},
  'names': [{'first_name': 'sean',
    'last_name': 'thorne',
    'suffix': None,
    'middle_name': None,
    'middle_initial': None,
    'name': 'sean thorne',
    'clean': 'sean thorne',
    'is_primary': True}],
  'locations': [{'name': 'san francisco, california, united states',
    'locality': 'san francisco',
    'region': 'california',
    'subregion': 'city and county of san francisco',
    'country': 'united states',
    'continent': 'north america',
    'type': 'locality',
    'geo': '37.77,-122.41',
    'postal_code': None,
    'zip_plus_4': None,
    'street_address': None,
    'address_line_2': None,
    'most_recent': True,
    'is_primary': True,
    'last_updated': '2019-01-01'}],
  'experience': [{'company': {'name': 'hallspot',
     'size': '1-10',
     'founded': '2013',
     'industry': 'computer software',
     'location': {'locality': 'portland',
      'region': 'oregon',
      'country': 'united states'},
     'profiles': ['linkedin.com/company/hallspot',
      'twitter.com/hallspot',
      'crunchbase.com/organization/hallspot',
      'linkedin.com/company/3019184'],
     'website': 'hallspot.com'},
    'locations': [],
    'end_date': '2015-02',
    'start_date': '2012-08',
    'title': {'levels': ['owner'],
     'name': 'co-founder',
     'functions': ['co founder']},
    'type': None,
    'is_primary': False,
    'most_recent': False,
    'last_updated': None},
   {'company': {'name': 'people data labs',
     'size': '11-50',
     'founded': '2015',
     'industry': 'information technology and services',
     'location': {'locality': 'san francisco',
      'region': 'california',
      'country': 'united states'},
     'profiles': ['linkedin.com/company/peopledatalabs',
      'linkedin.com/company/1640694639'],
     'website': 'peopledatalabs.com'},
    'locations': [],
    'end_date': None,
    'start_date': '2015-03',
    'title': {'levels': ['owner'],
     'name': 'co-founder',
     'functions': ['co founder']},
    'type': None,
    'is_primary': True,
    'most_recent': True,
    'last_updated': '2019-05-01'}],
  'education': [{'school': {'name': 'university of oregon',
     'type': 'post-secondary institution',
     'location': 'eugene, oregon, united states',
     'profiles': ['linkedin.com/edu/university-of-oregon-19207',
      'facebook.com/universityoforegon',
      'twitter.com/uoregon'],
     'website': 'uoregon.edu'},
    'end_date': '2014',
    'start_date': '2010',
    'gpa': None,
    'degrees': [],
    'majors': ['entrepreneurship'],
    'minors': [],
    'locations': []}]},
 'dataset_version': '7.3'}
```

While trying to get the phone_numbers field, I have tried:

```
print(json_response["phone_numbers"])
```

and got the error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-2acb0f9f59c5> in <module>()
----> 1 json_response["phone_numbers"]

KeyError: 'phone_numbers'
```

I am hoping to get the number '+14155688415' as my result

Comment: You should probably try `json_response["data"]["phone_numbers"]`. Or not... the JSON is kinda messy. You can pretty-print it with `import pprint;pprint.pprint(json_response)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(json_response["data"]["phone_numbers"])
```

When dealing with lots of data like that, [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) is a good resource to stay organized.